# Redirect To New Page After Submitting

Tags: html, redirect, submit, form-submit

This is my first ever post here. :)
I am new to programming and need to make a form that I am working on redirect to a new page after the forum has been submitted successfully. From what I understood based on my searching I need to change the "form action" so that it redirects. I have done it successfully but what happens is people actually redirect on clicking the "submit" button and don't submit the form.
Can you help me with the coding ?

`<form id="form1" name="form1" class="wufoo topLabel page" accept-charset="UTF-8" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" novalidate
      action="http://www.example.com/">`

I want the form to redirect after the submit button is clicked AND the form successfully submitted.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I am new to programming and don't really understand much. I am 1 month into learning it and can only code very simple C codes.
Would you mind explaining what you mean ?

Comment: Are you submitting your form using php?

Comment: Yes. Everything looks as it should but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" class="wufoo     topLabel page" accept-charset="UTF-8"    autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data"    method="post" novalidate   action="http://www.example.com/">
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

It will resolve your need

Comment: It didn't, look at my post down below. I included the full code.